# Regex representation for licence plate

Tags: regex

Pattern for example:

```
L(IP)-P(F)-2(014)
```

More examples:

```
B-G-2
BI-GH-1245
HH-X-124
```

The chars in brackets are optional. First (Max 3 chars, min 1) and second part (max 2 chars, min 1) consits of letters only. Third part (max 4. min 1) consists of numbers only. The parts are divided by "-".

Any ideas how a regex for this would look like?

Comment: Will it be those exact letters and numbers?  So for example is the first letter always L, or is that just a placeholder for any capital letter?

Comment: no that way just an example. may be any letters, and any numbers

Comment: Just  checking.  So some examples of legal ones would be L-P-2, LAB-PD-2 and LA-PD-201?  Or are L and P outside the parentheses variables too?

Comment: 3 years a member and about ~10K rep and you still don't know that you should try something ?

Comment: @HamZa hell ya I know ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the character class `[A-Z]` to match any uppercase character, and `\d` to match any digit.  You can specify repetition using `{m,n}`, which means "match the previous element between *m* and *n* times":

It might look something like this:

```
[A-Z]{1,3}-[A-Z]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,4}
```

You may also want to add beginning and end of string anchors (`^` and `$` respectively):

```
^[A-Z]{1,3}-[A-Z]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,4}$
```

This depends on whether you are trying to pull license plates out of a larger string or trying to see if a particular string is a license plate (and nothing else).

If you also need to match lowercase characters, change each of the `[A-Z]` classes to `[A-Za-z]`.

Comment: What about optional text in brackets?

Comment: The brackets don't exist, this is just how the OP chose to represent the optional characters.  The goal is to match 1-3 letters, a dash, 1-2 letters, a dash, and then 1-4 digits.  The recent edit to the question with a few examples supports my interpretation.

Comment: @F.J thank you, I am using it in java and it gives me an error "invalid escape sequence" http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Change the `\d` to `\\d` or `[0-9]`.  `\d` is how the regex should look but to actually put `\d` in a Java string it would look like `"\\d"` because the backslash needs to be escaped.

Comment: Just changed the answer to use `[0-9]` since according to the docs you linked `\d` will match any Unicode digit, including those from other languages.  In most other languages `\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]` unless a Unicode option is explicitly enabled.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this regex:

```
^[A-Za-z]{1,3}-[A-Za-z]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,4}$
```

Comment: Why the funny back references?

Comment: Where do you see back reference?

Comment: `(?:XXX)` is a non-capturing version of `(XXX)`.

Comment: Why do you allow parentheses? I think that was just the OP's way of showing that a portion is optional.

Comment: @Barmar: OP's first example had brackets and on top of this line: `The chars in brackets are optional.` confused me probably

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret you correctly, you basically need

<1-3 letters><1-2 letters><1-4 numbers>

or [A-Za-z]{1,3}-[A-Za-z]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,4}

Comment: I try it with python findall method but it can not find. Any suggesstions ?